# Why change the object properties of JQuery EasyUI will influence the original value?

Tags: javascript, web, jquery-easyui

I get an object data after use the inner method of easyui, and I need to deal with it before append it as a new row in datagrid.

Demo Code as followed.

var data = $('#id').datagrid('getRows')[0];

assume the content of the data variable is {'a':123}
if I deal with it as : data.a = 444;

and then run the same getRows command again:
var data2 = $('#id').datagrid('getRows')[0];

the result: {'a':444}

what happened?

Because easyui is an commerce code, It has been obfuscated, so I can't figure it out by read the source code.

I guess may be easyui implement the Set method, so after I change the properties, it will change the source data ?

Any help? Thanks.

[the real demo image of this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He0Cw.png)

Answer (score 0):

No one try to solve this question, then I continue work to it.

After beautify the jquery.easyui.min.js file by jsnice.org, I found such a struct：

```
$.fn.datagrid.parseData = function (target) {
        var targets = $(target);
        var data = {
            total: 0,
            rows: []
        };
```

So all properties is store in variable at the very begin. If someone change the object value, the change will store instantly.